# PTIJ: Why do I need a mole for my grandson to be circumcised?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Mazal Tov! My daughter gave birth to a healthy boy a few days ago. She has asked me to find a mole to circumcise my grandson.

I don't understand that at all. The baby has such beautiful soft baby skin. Why does he need a mole before he can be circumcised? Did my daughter mean that I need a mole? I don't have any moles, and I wouldn't even know how to make one within the next week.

--

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Why do people keep downvoting the Purim Torah questions!?

Comment: @ezra it wasn't me in this case, but if I think something is a bad purim question (or answer), I will downvote it.  That's what voting is for.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות It just seems someone is going on a downvote craze. I have to really, really dislike a question or answer to downvote it. In most cases, I leave the post alone, neither upvoting nor downvoting.

Comment: I always thought it was pronounced something like "moil", short for Mole Oil(or maybe Mohel Oil?) - the best thing to sooth and heal freshly cut skin.  Keep that baby's skin soft with less toil - use Doyle's Royal Mohel Oil!

Comment: @ezra It wasn't me either, but don't we have too many of them? It's only Rosh Chodesh, and more than the half of the questions are these ones...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Please flag for deletion and comment if this is too inappropriate. I do not mean to offend.

A [mole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_(espionage)) is necessary for a circumcision because we need the mole to access something private.

Answer (score 5):

She was referring to a *mole*, the classic spicy chocolate and chicken dish served at every Mexican bris. Your son-in-law is obviously from a nice Mexican Jewish family and so they have to follow Mexican Minhag

Answer (score 4):

I think that she got confused and mistranslated Tzaras as a mole; she must have heard about it from someone who was very excited about being able to get rid of tzaras beheter.

Comment: Tzara'at is not a mole, from my understanding.

Comment: No, of course not. But hey, this is purim torah anyway, and they are both marks on skin.

Answer (score 3):

I think she wants you to find a "mole animal" as it has extra thumbs. She probably wants the procedure done by one with extreme dexterity.

Comment: I didn't think of that one!